# Python asynchronous subprocess doesn't show the output if started via batch file

Tags: python, batch-file, subprocess

I have a python script(`MainScript.py`), which I'm using to start another python script when certain conditions are true, and this other script takes a long time to finish. It is important to be able to see, how that subprocess is doing, but currently this is not working. Environment is Windows 10. Code so far:

```
asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsProactorEventLoopPolicy())
proc = await asyncio.subprocess.create_subprocess_shell("python SuperLongScript.py", stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)
        
   while True:
      output = await proc.stdout.read(1024)
      print(str(output, "utf-8"))
```

Interesting thing is, that this is working if I start the `MainScript.py` script from VS Code in debug, but when I start this via .bat script, the output of the `SuperLongScript.py` can not be seen.

Here's the script inside that .bat file:

```
@ECHO OFF
cd "path\to\the\script"
python MainScript.py
```

And I have made a shortcut of this, because I want to start this MainScript in minimized.